# JavaScript selector with attribute value

Tags: javascript, dom

This is my html code

```
<p foo="bar">Lorem Ipsum color dot....</p>
```

Now, I want to select this tag with another javascript code. I can do this by selecting the p tag with this code:-

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
```

But, what will I do when the p is not number 0? when there is more p tags before this p tag?

I want to select this tag with the foo name as like id works. I can select the attr using Id.

```
document.getElementById("any");
```

But I need something like this:

```
document.getElementByFoo("bar");
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use CSS selectors with `querySelectorAll`. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName(names);  ?

Comment: What's your use case? (What's really `foo`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll)

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('p[foo="bar"]')[0]
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gd525/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a "modern"" browser (IE >= 8) you can use `querySelector` which allows you to use CSS stype selectors.

In your case you would use `document.querySelector ('p[foo="bar"]')` which would return the first `p` element with an attribute `foo="bar"`. There is also `querySelectorAll` whcih returns a collection of all elements conforming to the selection criteria.

Both `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` may be applied to any element in addition to `document`.

For further information consult your preferred DOM reference site or do a search.

Comment: IE8 supports querySelector